# Как вывести каждый элемент массива через заданный интервал

Tags: javascript

Как мне реализовать вывод элементов массива, например, через 2 секунды? То есть выводится 1-й элемент, проходит 2 секунды, выводится 2-й, еще 2 секунды - выводится третий и тд. По идее надо положить setTimeout в forEach, но у меня получилось что-то не то.

```
const fib = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];

for (let i = 0; i < fib.length; i++) {
  fib.forEach(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(fib[i]);
    }),
      2000;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const fib = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21];

fib.forEach((el, i) => setTimeout(() => console.log(el), 2000 * (i + 1)));
```